# how to print this map ( java) Map <String ,List<Edge>> graph = new HashMap<String, List<Edge>>();

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

```
Map <String ,List<Edge>> graph = new HashMap<String, List<Edge>>();
```

this is the map 
i filled it with nodes(String) and edges(neighbor(String),weight(int)) ı can print the keys but ı couldnt reach the neighbor and weight variables thanks for the help

```
public class Edge {

    String Destination;
    int weight;

}
```

main class just read from txt some data like
(node)1.(to)2(50(weight)) in this pattern

Comment: what it prints then, when you write `System.out.println(graph.toString());`.???

Comment: provide your `Edge` class and also willing to know what you tried to print??

Comment: 8=[Edge@5c647e05, Edge@5c647e05, Edge@5c647e05, Edge@5c647e05, Edge@5c647e05, Edge@5c647e05, Edge@5c64.................................................

Comment: ok...in that case override method `public String toString()` in class `Edge.java` and return `String` from that method to print variables...

Comment: if so, then close your question by accepting the answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add one method in your `Edge.java` class which will return neighbor and weight variables like this..

```
public String toString() {
    return "(" + neighbor + " : " + weight + ")";
}
```

and it will print correct output..